# Are military aircraft required to have black boxes?

Tags: faa-regulations, military, flight-data-recorder, cockpit-voice-recorder

In the United States, the FAA [requires](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1685/6919) certain types of aircraft to have a Flight Data Recorder (FDR) and/or Cockpit Voice Recorder (CVR).  I understand these regulations to apply mostly to civil aviation.  Does it apply to military aircraft as well?

Another [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11369/6919) researched whether fighters *have* them or not; my question is whether they are *required* to, and for military aircraft in general, not just fighters.

Comment: The answers to http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12401/how-much-jurisdiction-does-the-faa-have-over-military-aircraft suggest that FAA regulations generally are not binding on the military.

Comment: Do you mean "do the FAA regs apply," or would military regulations also count as requiring it?

Comment: @cpast both preferably, although i'm thinking the faa would have some sort of exemption codified in the cfr.

Answer (score 2):

Military aircraft need not adhere to FAA regulations. Modern military aircraft with digital controls have black boxes, older ones may not.

Answer (score 2):

No. The FAA has no enforcement ability over the US military.

As far as airworthiness and certification, the Federal Aviation Act, Section 610, specifically states that its provisions only apply to "air commerce" and "civil" aircraft.